# Eevee - Texture without distortion on multiple objects

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

Here are two mockups what I basically want:

So I have object of different shape:
[image: objects]

And I want a shader setup which puts the same texture on multiple objects without distortion, using the origin of the objects. Like this:
[image]

In Blender 2.90 I have a simple shader setup with "Texture Coordinate - Camera" - "(Vector) Mapping Point" - "Texture Image" so the texture always faces the camera. But I cant get it working that the origin of the objects is used for the texture.

[image: screenshot of original node setup]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve, it sounds to me like camera mapping but I'm not sure. Do you have a reference video or something like that?

Comment: I tried to explain it more clearly. I don't think it's the usual camera mapping.

Comment: This seems to be way easier to do in compositing. You can use material index to mask a certain material in the compositing and just overlay the texture on it.